# Error: No controller: ngModel for Angular Typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a mix of Jquery and angular and I'm trying to display a dialog with a Typeahead inside.
For objective reasons, I display a modal body and appended  it with the Angular typeAhead directive.

```
$('.modal-builder .modal-body').append('<input type="text" placeholder="Start typing product title" typeahead="item.title for item in getAutoCompleteProducts($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control input inline" typeahead-wait-ms="200" typeahead-min-length="0" typeahead-on-select="insertProduct($item)" /><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg" ng-show="loadingLocations" > </i>');
```

after this I try to compile it:

```
var cr = $('.modal-builder .modal-body').append('<div class="row"></div>');
$compile(cr)(scope);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error: No controller: ngModel
```

The scope is also from a Angular Bootstrap dialogue directive. Inside it I have various buttons to display the dialogue with the TypeAhead.

I read other questions on Stack and looks like an error between the scopes of the directives. I could not solve it by doing separate scopes.

Should it be compiled in a complete new scope?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add ngModel directive to your typeahead template:

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="product.selected"
       placeholder="Start typing product title" 
       typeahead="item.title for item in getAutoCompleteProducts($viewValue)"
       ...
```

But such a mix of jQuery with Angular is not a very good idea.

Comment: looks like it's working. I should get rid of Jquery, I know. Thank you.

Comment: I would say you should use jQuery properly with Angular, more directives, avoid any DOM manipulations outside of angular app directives.